# Application defined exception in Delphi application, with Indy SMTP and TLS

Tags: delphi, ssl, smtp, indy

I use the following (simplified) code to send an e-mail in my Delphi 5 command line application:

```
  Smtp := TIdSmtp.Create (nil);
  Smtp.Host     := 'smtp.office365.com';
  smtp.Port     := 587;
  Smtp.UserName := 'info@aaaaaa.com';
  Smtp.Password := '********';
  Smtp.AuthType := satDefault;
  Smtp.UseTLS    := utUseExplicitTLS;

  HandlerSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Smtp);
  HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  HandlerSocket.PassThrough := False;
  Smtp.IOHandler := HandlerSocket;

  //Create message in helper object
  SmtpWrapper.Sender := 'o@aaaaaa.com';
  SmtpWrapper.Recipients := adminAddresses;
  SmtpWrapper.ReplyToName := 'm@x-net.com';
  SmtpWrapper.Body := 'Invalid Keys in order: ' + #13#10;
  SmtpWrapper.Subject := ' OrderNo';

  TRY
    Smtp.Connect;
    try
      if not Smtp.Authenticate then
        raise Exception.Create ('SMTP Authentification Error');
      Smtp.Send (SmtpWrapper.IdMsg);
    finally
      Smtp.Disconnect;
    end;

  EXCEPT
    ON E : exception DO BEGIN
      ShowMessage ('Elmar Exception: ' + E.message);
    END;
  END;
```

Everything goes well, when there is no error returned from the SMTP server.
However, when there is an error then an Exception is thrown from TIdReplySMTP.RaiseReplyError.
The exception is caught and rethrown in TIdSMTPBase.SendNoPipelining. 
In that position, my application stops with an Application defined exception.

Did anyone experience this?

I'm using Delphi 5, Indy 10.6.2 and OpenSSL 1.0.2f.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You can't set the `UseTLS` property before setting the `IOHandler` property, you should be getting an `EIdTLSClientSSLIOHandlerRequred` exception from the `UseTLS` property setter. Also, because you are using `utUseExplicitTLS` (ie, `STARTTLS` handling), DO NOT set the IOHandler's `PassThrough` property to False! It needs to be True initially in order for `STARTTLS` to work.

Comment: As for the "Application defined" error, it means your Delphi debugger has a bug, it is not handling re-raised exceptions correctly.  Try going into the Debugger settings and tell it to ignore the exception code (I am assuming `c0000008`) that you are seeing in the popup message.

Comment: You are right with the first - I made a mistake copying it from my actual code.
Unfortunately it is not only a debugger bug. The application is also dying when running outside the debugger. It might rather have to do with Delphi 5 - either the compiler or the Indy library. I lately tried to run it with XE5, where it worked correctly

Comment: It is a Delphi issue, not an Indy issue.  Yes, Indy does re-raise catch exceptions at times, and that code is perfectly valid. Delphi 5 simply does not always handle re-raised exceptions correctly. It works fine in Delphi 6 onward.